# Can UICollectionView count horizontally?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, alignment

I have this from a programmatically implemented UICollectionView:

[image]

Is there a way (programmatically) to ask it to count left to right instead of top to bottom so that there would be two rows of four instead of two columns? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a flow layout you can set the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`'s `scrollDirection` property to `UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical`:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = collectionView.layout;
layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;
```